# Azure devops, create another board

Tags: azure-devops

I want to create another board to my backlog items, but i cannot figure out how to do this without creating another team with a separate backlog.

I don't want to create another project but want to remain in the same project.

I just want two ways to visualize the same data

I cant find any information when i google this

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways of displaying information about the backlog. A Board is an interactive way of looking at the backlog, so there's no way of creating two for the same backlog.

> Azure Boards provides software development teams with the **interactive and customizable tools** they need to manage their software projects. It provides a rich set of capabilities including native support for Agile, Scrum, and Kanban processes, calendar views, configurable dashboards, and integrated reporting.

You might be looking for [Dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/overview?view=azure-devops).

> ##### Configurable dashboards and Power BI reports
>
> With dashboards, teams can create customized views to gain visibility into their status, view progress, and analyze trends. Dashboards provide flexibility to share information and improve workflow processes. Each team can tailor their dashboards to share information and monitor their progress.
>
> [image: Dashboard example]
>
> Also, you can use Power BI to create custom, complex reports based on custom queries of the Analytics service. The Analytics service is the reporting platform for Azure DevOps. It is optimized for fast read-access and server-based aggregations. Use it to answer quantitative questions about the past or present state of your projects.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate response, i will look in to Power BI and see if i can get some useful analytics out of it.

My dilemma is that i have two teams in one team with different focuses. It would have been nice to have to interactive boards, one for each focus of the smaller teams.